# Does sklearn supports feature selection on dynamic data?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, feature-selection, dynamic-data

`sklearn` contains Implementation of different feature selection methods (`filter/wrapper/embedded)`.

All those methods designed for static systems.

Does `sklearn` supports feature selection on dynamic data ? (Data which vary with time)

In dynamic data, we need to improve the efficiency of feature selection, in order to be more effective.

I found some methods on IEEE (Incremental approaches for feature selection), 
So is there any implementation at `sklearn` or other open-source library ?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just re-run your process on a scheduled basis and load your data dynamically?  I wouldn't expect the dependent variable to change at all, but I suppose the independent variables could change somewhat.

```
#1)  load your dataframe
#2)  copy your target variable into a new dataframe

y = df[['SeriousDlqin2yrs']]

#3)  drop your target variable

x = df[df.columns[df.columns!='SeriousDlqin2yrs']]
```

Finally, run this.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
features = np.array(x)
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
clf.fit(x, y)
# from the calculated importances, order them from most to least important
# and make a barplot so we can visualize what is/isn't important
importances = clf.feature_importances_
sorted_idx = np.argsort(importances)
padding = np.arange(len(features)) + 0.5
plt.barh(padding, importances[sorted_idx], align='center')
plt.yticks(padding, features[sorted_idx])
plt.xlabel("Relative Importance")
plt.title("Variable Importance")
plt.show()
```

I just tried that, and got this result.

[image]

If you expect to get non-numeric features, you will need to use one hot encoding to handle these.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.get_dummies(df)
```

http://queirozf.com/entries/one-hot-encoding-a-feature-on-a-pandas-dataframe-an-example